# I want to find the difference between two timestamps using COBOL

Tags: cobol

I want to the find difference between two timestamps using COBOL.
my timestamp is 16 bytes and here is the ex. of one timestamp: 2010060314314826 
Please provide the sample code

Comment: Which COBOL are you using. What is the operating environment?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in an IBM mainframe environment with LE support, try looking up:
[CEESECS--Convert timestamp to seconds](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/CEEA3160/2.2.5.58?DT=20050629120436).
Using this routine you can convert each of your timestamps to Lilian seconds, then subtract one from
the other giving a result in seconds.

This same guide 
provides [COBOL code](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/CEEA3160/2.2.5.58.3?SHELF=&DT=20050629120436&CASE=) 
to do exactly what you are looking for.  About the only change you need to make in this example is to the format of the timestamp as follows:

```
MOVE "YYYYMMDDHHMISS99" TO Vstring-text of PICSTR.
```

You may convert the seconds count into the number of days, hours, minutes etc. using 
the [CEESECI--Convert seconds to integers](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/CEEA3160/2.2.5.57?DT=20050629120436)
service. Again, specific COBOL examples are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably formatted as:

YYYY MM DD HH MM SS CC

MOVE the timestamps in two fields such as:

```
 01 field-to-load.
    03 year   pic(9999).
    03 month  pic(99).
    03 day    pic(99).
    03 hour   pic(99).
    03 min    pic(99).
    03 sec    pic(99).
    03 cents  pic(99).
```

and perform the date/time arithmetic with the levels 03.

If your timestamps are not display-type data, you may need to do a previous conversion. If you need more detail about it post the field definition for the timestamp field.

I hope not to be banned from SO for posting cobol code.

HTH.

### Edit

[Here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.sys.hp.mpe/2006-02/msg00203.html) you can find a HP COBOL program for calculating date differences. You only have to add the (hour, min, sec) logic, very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your version of Cobol has date/time math, you have two choices:

1) convert the date stamp into number of seconds per year since some arbitrary past date (17-nov-1978 for example), do the same with the date/time you are comparing it to, do a simple subtraction between the two results, and then convert the resulting number of seconds back into a delta time difference, or

2) subtract each portion of the date/time separately, account for the number of days in each month, and leap years (if you want it to work for more than 4 years).  this option gets really hairy and has a very high failure rate, so I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Cobol 85 has built in date functions that will help.

```
COMPUTE FOO = FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE(YYYYMMDD).
COMPUTE FOO2 = FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE(DATEVAR).

COMPUTE DIFF = FOO2 - FOO.
```

Comment: These functions deal with dates, not timestamps, as in the question.